# R ggplot change xtick from full date to day of the week

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the xtick on my line plot from date to text (showing the name of the day of the week.

I have the following code but the xtick are currently not showing. Can anyone help me?

```
lab_day <- c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
'Saturday', 'Sunday')
ggplot(stats.gender.wdayF, aes(x=date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=stats.gender.wdayF$sum), color = 'red') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=stats.gender.wdayF$sum), color = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(y=stats.agg.wday$sum), color = 'grey') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=stats.agg.wday$sum), color = 'grey') +
  scale_x_date(labels = lab_day) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Number of runs") 

dataset looks like:
date, sum
17/12/2017, 1
18/12/2017, 10
19/12/2017, 25
20/12/2017, 2
21/12/2017, 33
22/12/2017, 5
22/12/2017, 11
```

Comment: we do not have your dataset `stats.gender.wdayF`. So provide as reproducible example.

Comment: done. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share that dataset (for future reference too). It is rather cumbersome for someone to type in those values manually.

Comment: also, we don't have `stats.agg.wday`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create the name of the date in another column and then use the `scale_x_discrete()` to make the x_axis labels. This would be much easier.

for example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

stats.gender.wdayF <- read.table(text = "date2 sum gender
17/12/2017 1 m
18/12/2017 10 F
19/12/2017 25 m 
20/12/2017 2 m
21/12/2017 33 m
22/12/2017 5 m
22/12/2017 11 F", header = T)%>% as.data.table()

stats.gender.wdayF[, lab_day2 := weekdays(date2 %>% as.Date())]

ggplot(stats.gender.wdayF, aes(x=date2 %>% as.character())) +
  geom_line(aes(y=sum), color = 'red') + 
  geom_point(aes(y=sum), color = 'red') +
  # geom_line(aes(y=stats.agg.wday$sum), color = 'grey') + 
  # geom_point(aes(y=stats.agg.wday$sum), color = 'grey') +
  # scale_x_date(date_labels = '%d %b %Y', date_minor_breaks = '1 day') +
  scale_x_discrete( labels  = stats.gender.wdayF$lab_day2 %>% paste(stats.gender.wdayF$date2, sep = '\n'))  
  # xlab("") +
  # ylab("Number of runs")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, R cannot find function := . I'm not sure why R does not something so simple

Comment: @federicozampu I believe you need to load the `dplyr` package for "%>%" and the `data.table` package for ":=". I've tried George Sotiropoulos' code, & it does produce the plot here.

Comment: I apology. Thank you

Comment: @federicozampu If eventually works for you then you can upvote and accept the answer so as the question is closed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **format="%A"** to your scale_x_date() function - I believe that should fix it...

If that doesn't work, according to the [tidyverse](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html), "A character vector giving labels (must be same length as `breaks`)". In your case `breaks` is null so I feel like that may be the issue. Perhaps try adding the breaks argument?

Comment: Note, this should just reformat the dates on the x-axis to dayname format, I don't think it will actually group the data. I know you didn't ask to group tour data based on dayname, but if that is actually what you're looking for, that would require some additional code.